# Deny exim4 to receive all emails

Tags: debian, email, exim, debian-jessie, deny

I have a fresh `exim4` install without any tweaks on a `Debian 8.6` machine.

I use it to send emails from PHP:

```
; /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/mail.ini 
[mail function]
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/exim4 -t
mail.add_x_header = On
mail.log = syslog
```

Recently we began to receive a lot of spam emails, which exim tries to send back, because of inexistent recepients.

So, my question is:
how to completely deny `exim4` to receive any external emails?
(Maybe excluding some local emails like cron ones.)

Thank you.

---

As pointed by **@slipeer** my Exim already not receiving any external emails. So I created a different question:

[Deny some local users (not addresses) to send email from exim4](https://serverfault.com/questions/826121/deny-some-local-users-not-addresses-to-send-email-from-exim4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it you need to relay outbound emails from php local.

Try run:

```
dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

Then:

1. Select **'internet site'** configuration.
2. Enter your system’s FQDN
3. Configure `127.0.0.1` as listening IP (or `127.0.0.1; ::1` if you use IPv6)
4. Specify local domains. Here you should specify the domain names, the  which mails will be delivered locally. (If you need to deliver locally only emails with recipients like `somebody@localhost`, you can specify only `localhost` here)
5. Leave the relay domains field blank.
6. Leave the relay machines field blank.
7. Select local mail storage format. I recommend **'Maildir'**
8. Select generated exim config format.  I recommend **'non-split'** - allconfig in one file

This guid with screens [can found here](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/exim/sendonly-mail-server-with-exim-on-debian-6-squeeze) (screenshots for Debian 6, but since that time they have not changed.).

Comment: — on step 3 I have **127.0.0.1 ; ::1**; — on step 4: **subdomail.domain.com** (should I paste **localhost** here?); — 5-6 are blank; — 7: **mbox**; — 8: **non-split**

Comment: Of course, if you have configured and used ipv6, the line will look like this. I'll add it to my ansver.

Comment: Sorry for being lame: how can I check if my exim4 is send-only?

Comment: When your Exim accept connections only on the loopback interface - it can not accept emails from the outside. To check it run: `netstat -lnp | grep -i exim`

Comment: I have: http://sishot.ru/i/bUVYSnG-AG9n

Comment: That's ok. You exim accepts only local connections.

Comment: So, my problem is not there and my Exim already is not receiving any external emails! Thank you for your time. But how Exim is sending such amount of emails then? Created a different question: http://serverfault.com/questions/826121/deny-some-local-users-not-addresses-to-send-email-from-exim4