# Deny some local users (not addresses) to send email from exim4

Tags: debian, email, exim, debian-jessie

I have a fresh `exim4` install without any tweaks on a `Debian 8.6` machine.

I use it to send emails from PHP:

```
; /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/mail.ini 
[mail function]
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/exim4 -t
mail.add_x_header = On
mail.log = syslog
```

Recently we began to receive a lot of spam emails, which exim tries to send back, because of inexistent recepients.

So, I ran exim statistics tool and got:

```
# /usr/sbin/eximstats -ne -byhost -bydomain -byemail /var/log/exim4/mainlog

Top 50 local senders by message count
-------------------------------------
  Messages      Bytes    Average   Local sender
       603     1395KB       2368   Debian-exim
        38      127KB       3422   website1user
        33       94KB       2916   website2user
         7       91KB       13KB   website3user
```

Normal sites send tens of emails per day, and `Debian-exim` user sends hundreds of ones to some random addresses, which I even don’t know.

How can I completely deny some specified users to send emails through `exim4`?
Should I deny `Debian-exim` user? What is it used for?
Notice that I mean **not sender email addresses** to deny (they can be replaced with no effort in headers of the email) but **local users** here.

(Maybe I have completely lost an understanding of situation?)

Thank you.

Comment: This is a normal letter, formed by local shippers - your php scripts. I believe that *websiteXuser* - user names under which the work sites. You need to examine the `/var/log/exim4/mainlog` for the person to whom the emails from *websiteXuser* is addressed. This will provide information to fix problem.

Comment: **websiteXusers** send legit emails: all of them are normal and legitimate. My main concern is about abnormally huge amount of letters from **Debian-exim** account. How can this be?

Comment: Then check it recipients and ID. `exim -Mvh <id>` command will show you this message headers, and `exim -Mvb <id>` show it's body.

Comment: Maybe it’s easier to deny **Debian-exim** to send any letters?

Comment: It's not a good idea. Letters from the **Debian-exim** likely to contain diagnostic information about delivery problems - you should check their content and to whom they are addressed (probably it for root).

Comment: They are for random addresses, not even for local users. that *IS* the problem which I am trying to solve.

Comment: Can you provide example exim main log for this mails in your question?